# GLSL float/vec3/vec4 array max size = GL_MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_VECTORS?

Tags: opengl, glsl

I run

```
glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_VECTORS, &maxVertUniformsVect);
```

and get 1024.

Than in GLSL I do

```
uniform mediump vec4[1020] instance_mat
```

and that was ok. But with vec3/vec2/float it fails:

```
uniform mediump float[1030] instance_mat;          // fails
//uniform mediump vec2[1030] instance_mat;         // and this
//uniform mediump vec3[1030] instance_mat;         // and this
```

With following error:

> cannot locate suitable resource to bind variable "instance_mat".
>   Possibly large array.

The question is:
Does GL_MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_VECTORS return the number of all kind of arrays, no matter what size they are? I mean, no matter does this float/vec2/vec3/vec4 - all counts as one 
VERTEX_UNIFORM_VECTOR?

---

Vertex shader code, as is:

```
#version 120
uniform mediump float[1200] instance_mat;        //mat4x3
attribute mediump float instaceIdF;             // in range 0..1000 Will be converted to int

attribute mediump vec3 vertex_;
attribute lowp vec4 color;
uniform mediump mat4 matrix;
varying lowp vec4 v_color;

void main(void)
{
    v_color = color;


        int instaceId = int(instaceIdF) * 12;
        mediump mat4 offsetMat = mat4(
                                    vec4(instance_mat[instaceId],   instance_mat[instaceId+1], instance_mat[instaceId+2], 0),
                                    vec4(instance_mat[instaceId+3], instance_mat[instaceId+4], instance_mat[instaceId+5], 0),
                                    vec4(instance_mat[instaceId+6], instance_mat[instaceId+7], instance_mat[instaceId+8], 0),
                                    vec4(instance_mat[instaceId+9], instance_mat[instaceId+10], instance_mat[instaceId+11], 1)
                                 );

        /*mediump mat4 offsetMat = mat4(
                                    vec4(instance_mat[instaceId].xyz, 0),
                                    vec4(instance_mat[instaceId+1].xyz, 0),
                                    vec4(instance_mat[instaceId+2].xyz, 0),
                                    vec4(instance_mat[instaceId+3].xyz, 1)
                                 );*/
        gl_Position = matrix * offsetMat * vec4(vertex_, 1.0);
        //gl_Position = matrix * vec4(vertex, 1.0);


}
```

Comment: GL_MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_COMPONENTS returns aprox 16000. And I have nVidia, not ATI. So I think its true. :)

Comment: Can you show your entire shader? I think there is some confusion here, and the information in the accepted answer is incorrect. `GL_MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_VECTORS` refers to the sum total maximum size of all active uniforms in the vertex shader stage. If you have any other uniforms, the maximum length of an array you can support will be smaller.

Comment: Thank you for updating your question. Now, your issue is actually the version of GLSL you are using. There is no such thing as `GL_MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_VECTORS` in GLSL 1.20. All you have is `GL_MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_COMPONENTS`. In GLSL, this constant can be referenced by: `gl_MaxVertexUniformComponents` and it has a minimum implementation limit of 512. You are consuming 1200 + 16 uniform components in your vertex shader (1200 for the array and 16 for the mat4). Try declaring something along the lines of: `uniform mediump float instance_mat [gl_MaxVertexUniformComponents - 16];`

Comment: You also have your array subscript around the wrong part of the declaration if you are trying to create a uniform array.

Comment: "uniform mediump float instance_mat [gl_MaxVertexUniformComponents - 16];" - Same error.

Comment: "You also have your array subscript around the wrong part of the declaration if you are trying to create a uniform array."  - I try to create uniform array of matrices 3x4. What is wrong with it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43850/discussion-between-tower120-and-andon-m-coleman)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Uniform_%28GLSL%29 (Implementation limits):

> Implementation note: OpenGL implementations are allowed to reject
>   shaders for implementation-dependent reasons. So you can have fewer
>   active uniform components by your reckoning and still fail to link due
>   to uniform limits. This is usually on hardware that is innately vector
>   hardware. Pre-GeForce 8xxx hardware, and all ATi hardware does this.
>   In this case, you should assume that each separate uniform takes up 4
>   components, much like it would in D3D. That means **a "uniform float"
>   is 4 components**, a mat2x4 is 16 components (each row is 4
>   components), but a mat4x2 is 8 components.

Which is my case, also. But it not has to be always like that.
Of course, for compatible reasons it is always better to count each float/vec2/vec3 uniform value, as max size value (vec4)

Comment: I believe this is related: https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/182957-GLSL-pads-int-arrays-to-16-bytes-taking-4-times-local-memory

Answer (score 2):

The [OpenGL Docs](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/xhtml/glGet.xml) says it all.

`GL_MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_VECTORS`

> data returns one value, the maximum number of 4-vectors that may be held in uniform variable storage for the vertex shader. The value of GL_MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_VECTORS is equal to the value of GL_MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_COMPONENTS and must be at least 256.

Thereby that means that no matter the type, you can only hold an array of max `GL_MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_VECTORS` in length. Even though that `vec4 == 4 floats`

The maximum value of course vary by the different hardward implementations and how old/new the individual graphics card may be of OpenGL.

Comment: That is the GLSL ES specification you quoted. It has half the requirements of desktop GLSL on this matter. `const int gl_MaxVertexUniformVectors = 256;` in desktop GLSL.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Thanks for the comment, guess I posted a little too fast, but it's fixed now.

Comment: Also, I would not trust the online manual pages, because that information is clearly wrong. If you read the [OpenGL 4.4 specification](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec44.core.pdf), on pg. 117 (**7.6 Uniform Variables**) it contradicts the statement that the value of that implementation-defined constant is identical to `GL_MAX_UNIFORM_VECTOR_COMPONENTS`. The GLSL specification agrees with the OpenGL 4.4 specification, so I have serious doubts about the accuracy of anything on that manual page, particularly since the value listed 1 line above is 1024, which is not 256.

Comment: @Andon M. Coleman - I'm a little bit misunderstood... Can I rely on GL_MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_VECTORS as a max number of vec4?

Comment: @Tower120: Yes, but the information in this answer is incorrect. It is not the fault of Vallentin, just whoever misinterpreted this sentence in the OpenGL specification to create that page: "The implementation-dependent constants **MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_VECTORS** and **MAX_FRAGMENT_UNIFORM_VECTORS** have values respectively equal to the values of **MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_COMPONENTS** and **MAX_FRAGMENT_UNIFORM_COMPONENTS** divided by four." The page should ***actually*** say that `GL_MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_VECTORS` is equal to the value of `GL_MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_COMPONENTS` divided by four.

Comment: It is also incorrect to infer from that information that no matter the type the maximum array length is `GL_MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_VECTORS`, because a `mat4` uniform consumes 16 components. Which is 4x as many components as a `vec4`.

Comment: @tower120: Actually, I misread your original comment. That is not the maximum size of an array. That is the maximum number of `vec4`-sized uniforms you can have active in the vertex shader stage. You have to add the size of all of your **used** uniforms together, and if they exceed that limitation you are out of luck.

Comment: @Andon M. Coleman - I don't want vec4, I want vec3 - but driver let me use them as many as vec4, not more. Reread my question. This IS the maximum size of ANY vec array. At least in my, beddest case. Only if I not do something wrong.

Comment: @tower120: I realize you are talking about `vec3`. But when OpenGL talks about a limit that includes the word `VECTOR` it means `vec4`. This applies to vertex attributes, uniforms, etc. For instance, a `mat4` variable has the same storage requirements as 4 vectors (or 16 components total). Thus, although Valentin's answer implies you can have an array of up to 1024 `mat4` uniforms that is not correct - you are limited to 256 `mat4`s because a `mat4` = 4 x `vec4`. The real limit you need to observe is `MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_COMPONENTS`.

Comment: @Andon M. Coleman - He says about 1024 vec4, not mat4. Yes, I limited to 256 mat4. "The real limit you need to observe is MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_COMPONENTS" - ATI has a bug about this value (in 4 times more than it should be). And I CANT get 1040 float's, and according to MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_COMPONENTS - I should get at least 10000 of them. Wait, I'll make test shader with this and show you.