# GLSL packing 4 float attributes into vec4

Tags: opengl, attributes, glsl

I have a question about resource consumption of attribute `float` in glsl.

Does it take as many resources as `vec4`, or no?

I ask this, because uniforms takes https://stackoverflow.com/a/20775024/1559666 (at least, they could)

If it is not, then does it makes any sense to pack 4 `float`'s into one `vec4` attribute?

Comment: it is entirely possible that the driver will do that optimization anyway

Comment: Each attribute must have its own unique location in GLSL. This is the only storage limit that you can rely on when writing your shader, you know that GLSL gives a minimum (and usually maximum) of 16 vertex attribute slots and that a slot is large enough to store a `vec4` machine type. The driver cannot go around combining individual `float` attributes into a single slot, each one has its own location and the data for the `float` attribute only occupies 1/4 of the total potential storage at that location. So `float`, in this case, is quite wasteful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, ***all*** vertex attributes require some multiple of a 4-component vector for storage.

This means that a `float` vertex attribute takes 1 slot the same as a `vec2`, `vec3` or `vec4` would. And types larger than `vec4` take multiple slots. A `mat4` vertex attribute takes 4 x `vec4` many units of storage. A `dvec4` (double-precision vector) vertex attribute takes 2 x `vec4`. Since implementations are only required to offer 16 unique vertex attribute slots, if you naively used single `float` attributes, you could easily exhaust all available storage just to store a 4x4 matrix.

There is no getting around this. Unlike uniforms (scalar GPUs may be able to store `float` uniforms more efficiently than `vec4`), attributes are always tied to a 4-component data type. So for vertex attributes, packing attributes into vectors is quite important.

---

I have updated my answer to point out relevant excerpts from the GL and GLSL specifications:

#### [OpenGL 4.4 Core Profile Specification](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec44.core.pdf) - *10.2.1 Current Generic Attributes* - pp. 307

> Vertex shaders (see *section 11.1*) access an array of 4-component generic vertex
>   attributes. The ﬁrst slot of this array is numbered zero, and the size of the array is
>   speciﬁed by the implementation-dependent constant **`GL_MAX_VERTEX_ATTRIBS`**.

#### [GLSL 4.40 Specification](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.4.40.pdf) - *4.4.1 Input Layout Qualifiers* - pp. 60

> If a vertex shader input is any scalar or vector type, it will consume a single location. If a non-vertex shader input is a scalar or vector type other than **`dvec3`** or **`dvec4`**, it will consume a single location, while types **`dvec3`** or **`dvec4`** will consume two consecutive locations. Inputs of type **`double`** and **`dvec2`** will consume only a single location, in all stages.

Admittedly, the behavior described for `dvec4` differs slightly. In [`GL_ARB_vertex_attrib_64bit`](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/vertex_attrib_64bit.txt) form, double-precision types may consume twice as much storage as floating-point, such that a `dvec3` or `dvec4` may consume two attribute slots. When it was promoted to core, that behavior changed... they are only *supposed* to consume 1 location in the vertex stage, potentially more in any other stage.

#### Original (extension) behaviour of double-precision vector types:

> **Name**
>
> > `ARB_vertex_attrib_64bit`
> >
> > > [...]
> > >
> > > Additionally, some vertex shader inputs using the wider 64-bit components
> > >           may count double against the implementation-dependent limit on the number
> > >           of vertex shader attribute vectors.  A 64-bit scalar or a two-component
> > >           vector consumes only a single generic vertex attribute; three- and
> > >           four-component "long" may count as two.  This approach is similar to the
> > >           one used in the current GL where matrix attributes consume multiple
> > >           attributes.

Comment: That's what I want to hear. But could you, please, provide some proof link (for some opengl reference) ? :) Oh crap, I have to write glsl in question (updated) :)

Answer (score 0):

The attribute vec4 will take 4 times the memory of the attribute float.
On uniforms, due to some alignments, you may loose some components. (vec4 will be aligned to 4 bytes).

Comment: No, I mean, did single float takes so much memory as vec4?

Comment: as attribute no,
as uniform it depends, I'm not sure if the GLSL compiler will rearrange the uniforms to optimize the space used. The uniform itself will not use all the space, but the next uniform variable will be aligned to the next 4 bytes if it does not fit int the current 4 bytes block.