# How to write a heatmap shader that supports 1 milion data points in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader

I have a new requirement which is to integrate a heatmap for my current project that will support upwards to 1 million data points and project it on my terrain mesh.

I've read this post: https://www.alanzucconi.com/2016/01/27/arrays-shaders-heatmaps-in-unity3d/ and tried to implement it which after some tinkering was a success. The tinkering part was changing:

```
uniform float3 _Points [100]; // The positions (x,y,z)
uniform float2 _Properties [100] // The properties (x = radius, y = intensity)
```

to

```
uniform float4 _Points [100]; // The positions (x,y,z)
uniform float4 _Properties [100] // The properties (x = radius, y = intensity)
```

along with some tweaks to the script. I've managed to project upwards to 100 random points and the heatmap was rendered correctly. After I've cranked up the numbers, my FPS started to deteriorate dramatically and finally I've ran into the issue where I'm not allowed to have more than 1023 data points after which my shader crashes. Note that although I'm projecting my heatmap onto a 3D mesh I'm only using two data points (X,Z) as the end result should be a 2D heatmap.

How can I tackle this (for me) monstrosity of a task as 1023 points seems way too far from 1 milion so I presume I'm doing it very inefficiently.

In addition, this project has to run cross platform on Windows, Mac and Linux therefore I'd prefer OpenGL as renderer.

Comment: it depends what you use for graphics I guess e.g. for [OpenGL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20761237/glsl-float-vec3-vec4-array-max-size-gl-max-vertex-uniform-vectors)

Comment: I forgot to mention that this is a cross platform project so it has to run on Linux, Mac and Windows so OpenGL preferably

Comment: It sounds like you've engineered this so that you need to iterate through a million items on every frame.... I would start by seeing if you can maybe iterate through fewer things per frame. Maybe if you can iterate through the million things on the first frame to create a `texture2D` map (maybe using compute shader?) you then cache in c# then on each following frame you just iterate through a few points that have changed, change the `texture2D` accordingly, then send the updated `texture2D` to the render shader.

Comment: @Ilhan did you actually look at the link I posted? There it says that in OpenGL there is a certain limit of shader components that are allowed in total .. it is very small so you should try to findanother way .. not using arrays

Comment: Yes I've did but you just reminded me to mention the cross platform requirement

Comment: @Ruzihm I think your suggestion would work I just have to test it. Yes I've engineered it like you've said as that was the only thing that came to mind given my experience with the subject.

Comment: You're indeed not going to be able to shove everything into uniforms and hope that you can iterate over a million items per fragment. If I understand your problem correctly my approach would be to first render the points to a 3D texture and use that when rendering the final 2D-heat map.

Comment: for that many points you may want to simply place them on a texture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could divide the mesh you are rendering to into multiple meshes and pass to each one the points that should stay in that portion of the map. This way you can work around the limit of uniforms you have with a single mesh. 
I've worked with basically the same shader you are using, I would actually like to use a computer shader to pass more data but I'm no expert in that and for now I'll have to go with my solution.